# caption interfering with glossaries first/subsequent use mechanism

Tags: captions, glossaries

This is a follow-up question on [Glossaries in List of Figures overflow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97195/21591), where it was asked how the first usage scheme of the `glossaries` package can be used with a glossary term in a figure caption. I gave an answer that works as long as the `caption` package is not loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{acr}{%
  name        = {ACR-name},%
  description = {ACR-description},%
  first       = {ACR-first-description},%
}

\renewcommand{\glsdisplayfirst}[4]{#1 (1) #4}
\renewcommand{\glsdisplay}[4]{#1 (2+) #4}
\begin{document}
% \listoffigures %% even without \listoffigures the problem shows up

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption[Short title \glshyperlink{acr}]{Long title \gls{acr}}
\end{figure}

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

As can be seen, without `caption` the figure caption contains the first usage form of the glossary entry as desired, but with `caption` it is the subsequent use form.

How can I keep that working while using `caption`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LaTeX puts the caption inside a temporary scratch `\hbox`, measures its width. If the width is smaller than the line width, the *box* is reused to typeset the caption. Therefore `\gls` is called once. However if the caption width exceeds the line width, the caption text is set twice, this time as paragraph. Then `\gls` is called twice and you get the output for the second version of the glossary item.

Package `caption` makes the behaviour more predictable. If option `singlelinecheck` is set (default), then the caption text is always set twice, the first time for measuring the width to check if the text fits in one line and then the text is set again for the final result. With `singlelinecheck=false`, the measuring is disabled and the text is only set once, but the centering of the caption text gets lost.

A workaround is to put the result of `\gls{acr}` inside a temporary box and to use this box inside `\caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newsavebox\glsscratchbox

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{acr}{%
  name        = {ACR-name},%
  description = {ACR-description},%
  first       = {ACR-first-description},%
}

\renewcommand{\glsdisplayfirst}[4]{#1 (1) #4}
\renewcommand{\glsdisplay}[4]{#1 (2+) #4}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures %% even without \listoffigures the problem shows up

\begin{figure}[h]
  \sbox\glsscratchbox{\gls{acr}}
  \caption[Short title \glshyperlink{acr}]{Long title \unhcopy\glsscratchbox}
\end{figure}

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

(The command `\unhcopy` is used instead of `\usebox` (this is a `\copy`). It strips the outer `\hbox` layer and allows the spaces typeset in the same way as the other spaces in the line. Otherwise (`\usebox`) the space inside the reused box will always have the natural width.)

> [image: Result]

### Solution for `\gls` in the caption with package `caption`

Update: Simplification from Axel Sommerfeldt's comment added.

Package `glossaries` must remember first usages of the acronyms. The idea is to disable this, if the width of the caption is measured, but not, if the caption text is typeset finally.

Package `caption` is needed, because it separates the test from the final typesetting step. Also it provides macro `\caption@prepareslc` that precedes the measuring and is called before the measuring. There `\glsunset` is temporarily disabled for the measuring.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\caption@prepareslc{%
  \let\glsunset\@gobble
}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{acr}{%
  name        = {ACR-name},%
  description = {ACR-description},%
  first       = {ACR-first-description},%
}

\renewcommand{\glsdisplayfirst}[4]{#1 (1) #4}
\renewcommand{\glsdisplay}[4]{#1 (2+) #4}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption[Short title \glshyperlink{acr}]{Long title \gls{acr}}
\end{figure}

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

### Refinement

If `\gls{acr}` is used, a global flag is set for the acronym `acr` to remember the state of the acronym usage. Thus subsequent calls can use the shorter form.
The previous solution skipped the state setting, if the caption text is only measured. Thereby the state has not changed, when the caption text is finally set.

However, there is a situation that slips through. The caption text contains `\gls` with the same acronym several times including its first usage.
Then the previous solution would contain the first usage form of the acronym
for the usages of the acronym in the measuring step, because the state setting
has been disabled there.

This is fixed by allowing the normal state changes of the acronyms in the measuring step, but remembering the first usages. There are reset afterwards
before the final typesetting of the caption text.

Further remarks:

- A switch `\if@capmeasure` is introduced. Normally it is set to `\iffalse`.
  Whenthe width of the text is checked inside `\caption`, then it is set to `\iftrue`.
- Package `caption` is needed, because it separates the test from the final typesetting step. Also it provides macro `\caption@prepareslc` that
  precedes the measuring. Both are executed in the same local group.
  Therefore it is enough to add `\@capmeasurefalse` to `\caption@prepareslc`.
  The switch is automatically reset after the end of the group.
- After the measuring the state of the first acronym usages are reset.
- Package `glossaries`' `\glsunset` is patched to respect the setting of `\if@capmeasure` and remember first acronym usages.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@capmeasure
\g@addto@macro\caption@prepareslc{%
  \global\let\after@capmeasure\@empty
  \aftergroup\after@capmeasure
  \@capmeasuretrue
}
\CheckCommand*{\glsunset}[1]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#1}{%
    \expandafter \global \csname glo@#1@flagtrue\endcsname   
  }%
}
\renewcommand*{\glsunset}[1]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#1}{%
    \if@capmeasure
      \expandafter\ifx\csname ifglo@#1@flag\expandafter\endcsname
      \csname iftrue\endcsname
      \else 
        % first use
        \g@addto@macro\after@capmeasure{\glsreset{#1}}%
      \fi
    \fi
    \global\csname glo@#1@flagtrue\endcsname
  }%
}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{acr}{%
  name        = {ACR-name},%
  description = {ACR-description},%
  first       = {ACR-first-long-description},%
}

\renewcommand{\glsdisplayfirst}[4]{#1\textsuperscript{(1)}#4}
\renewcommand{\glsdisplay}[4]{#1\textsuperscript{(2+)}#4}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption[Short title \glshyperlink{acr}]%
  {Long title \textit{\gls{acr}} and \gls{acr}}
\end{figure}

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with refinement]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't see how this could be made into a nice interface, i.e., code that can be "hidden" in the preamble, or a small package, and let a user just use a special command like `\glscaption`.

Comment: @mafp I have added a solution that patches packages `caption` and `glossaries` accordingly.

Comment: Wouldn't be `\g@addto@macro\caption@prepareslc{\let\glsunset\@gobble}` sufficient? (If yes, I would add it to my `caption` package. I really would like to avoid patching the `glosseries` package...)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Thanks, solution simplified accordingly. However, the solution does not work, if the same acronym is used several times including its first usage form. Then the glossaries packages still needs to be patched.

Answer (score 0):

Using `glossaries-extra` you have two alternatives. See [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html).

1. You can always call `\glsxtrshort` within captions.
   These will not trigger first use, for obvious reasons.
   You also have the `noindex` and `hyper=false` options, if you want to also avoid links and don't want these entries to appear in a Glossary list created with `\printglossaries`.
   Which brings us to:
2. Predicting this usage, `glossaries-extra` includes the family of `\glsfmtshort` commands.
   These are identical to the corresponding `\glsxtrshort[noindex,hyper=false]` commands.
   So you have several similar commands, covering each of singular and plural forms, short, long and full forms, and lowercase, first letter uppercase and complete uppercase forms.